# How to put a spacing of colors in a table of xtable?

Tags: r, latex, bigtable, sweave, xtable

How to put a spacing of colors in a table of xtable?

I generate the tables with the following instructions:

```
test.table<-xtable(summary(test),caption='test', floating = FALSE)
align(test.table) <- "|c|l|"
print(test.table,caption.placement='top')
```

thanks  for  your  answers

Comment: Hey Ricardo, could you show us what you have now, and try to explain in more detail what you're looking to do with it?

Comment: What is `test`? What does `spacing of colors` mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `html.table.attributes` parameter needs a character vector of length equal to number of tables. This produces a bordered, centered table on a rather ugly yellow-orange background:

```
data(tli)
tli.table <- xtable(tli[1:20,])
digits(tli.table)[c(2,6)] <- 0
print(tli.table,type="html",
      html.table.attributes='border='1' align="center" bgcolor="#FFCC00"' )
```

And if you're targeting LaTeX use: `tabular.environment=`

Answer (score 1):

```
html.table.attributes = list('border="1" bgcolor="#FFCC00"'))
```

will work!