# R - Conditional row highlighting in HTML table created using xtable or kable

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, xtable

I'm pretty much a beginner at programmatically formatting R output, but I've got a basic understanding of `knitr`, `xtable`, Markdown, and Pandoc's ability to convert one markup format to another. What I want to do is write an R dataframe `df` to an HTML table, and apply a particular color to each row that meets a condition (e.g., `df$outcome == 1`). However, I'm not sure which package would accomplish this in a simple and efficient way, but from browsing a few table formatting threads ([`xtable` thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921025/xtable-highlighting-rowcolor-shifted-down-one-row), [`xtable` thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279973/how-to-put-a-spacing-of-colors-in-a-table-of-xtable), [`kable` documentation 1](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/knitr/docs/kable)), I've gathered that `kable` and `xtable` might be capable of accomplishing my desired result.

To clarify, here is my reproducible example (using `xtable`, but am interested in an answer using `kable` or another package as well):

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id       = sample(1:100, 20, replace = TRUE),
                 inputval = sample(seq(0, 1, by=0.01), 20, replace = TRUE),
                 outcome  = sample(1:4, 20, replace = TRUE))

library(xtable)
dfxt <- xtable(df)

knit2html(input      = "~/rowcolor_ex.Rmd",
          output     = OUTPUTHERE
          stylesheet = "STYLESHEET.css")
```

with`knit2html` referencing the file named "rowcolor_ex.Rmd", shown below:

````
```{r,echo=FALSE,results='asis',warning=FALSE,message=FALSE}
print(dfxt, 
      type = "html",
      include.rownames = FALSE,)
```
````

I understand that if I'm to use `xtable`, I'd include one or more arguments after the `print(dfxt,` part of the function call in the `Rmd` document, and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921025/xtable-highlighting-rowcolor-shifted-down-one-row) shows the `add.to.row` argument that makes sense for `type = "latex"`, but it isn't clear how the code would change for HTML output. Also, I'm not sure if referencing a CSS stylesheet in `knit2html` would override the HTML table's formatting.

Comment: [similar question about highlighting individual rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323885/how-to-color-specific-cells-in-a-data-frame-table-in-r)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a solution using `Gmisc::htmlTable`

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id       = sample(1:100, 20, replace = TRUE),
                 inputval = sample(seq(0, 1, by=0.01), 20, replace = TRUE),
                 outcome  = sample(1:4, 20, replace = TRUE))

cols <- with(df, ifelse(outcome == 1, 'magenta', 'white'))

library(Gmisc)
htmlTable(as.matrix(df), altcol = cols, 
          rgroup = '', n.rgroup = rep(1, length(cols)))
```

**EDIT**

Since `htmlTable` has since been moved to the package, `htmlTable`, and is no longer in `Gmisc` >= 1.0, the new way to do this would be

```
library('htmlTable')
htmlTable(as.matrix(df), col.rgroup = cols)
```

which also gives:

[image]

and your markdown code would simply be

````
```{r, results='asis'}
htmlTable(as.matrix(df), altcol = cols, 
          rgroup = '', n.rgroup = rep(1, length(cols)))
```
````

And my .Rmd would look like:

````
---
output: 
  html_document:
    css: ~/knitr.css
---

```{r, results='asis', message=FALSE}
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id       = sample(1:100, 20, replace = TRUE),
                 inputval = sample(seq(0, 1, by=0.01), 20, replace = TRUE),
                 outcome  = sample(1:4, 20, replace = TRUE))

cols <- with(df, ifelse(outcome == 1, 'magenta', 'white'))

library(Gmisc)
htmlTable(as.matrix(df), altcol = cols, 
          rgroup = '', n.rgroup = rep(1, length(cols)))
```
````

Comment: Wonderful! One question though. Since I'm using a data.frame with vectors of multiple types, I changed `as.matrix(df)` to just `df`, and now the first column is the table name (df) and includes row numbers. How do I remove this rownumber column? Thanks.

Comment: `rownames(df) <- NULL` or `rownames(df) <- rep('', nrow(df))`. It's just a habit of mine to turn everything into a matrix in these situations because 1) you can turn everything into character strings so the output respects your formatting and number of digits; 2) you can use duplicate row and column names (duplicate rownames not possible in data.frames which is why they will need to be there if you are using a data frame, hence why I coerce to a matrix usually)

Comment: Great, thanks. Also, can I specify a .css file from which htmlTable reads and applies the proper formatting? I have a .css file that applies to the rest of the HTML page, and want the tables to have uniform formatting, except for of course the rows that are highlighted a different color. Looks like `tableCSSclass = "table tr"` might inherit the `table tr` CSS from the CSS template I call in `knit2HTML`, but I see my table still shows the following class: `Classes 'htmlTable', 'character'  atomic [1:1] <table class='table tr' style='border-collapse: collapse;`

Comment: Yes you can do that. I have my css handle the table alignment, fonts, sizes, all that good stuff

Comment: OK, I see you have "gmisc_table" as the default CSS. When I change `tableCSSclass` to the filename of my CSS template, it still retains the default formatting. Can you append your answer above with an example of changing the CSS template? I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: oh I see. Not sure about that exactly. I usually use the yaml front matter to handle the css, see edits and [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/dz5cCvt.png). The tr formatting is embedded in the html which htmlTable produces, you can `cat(htmlTable(df))` to see. Not sure why the tableCSSclass would mess with that

Comment: is there a way to accomplish this where only one column is highlighted given the condition (i.e. so its not the whole row)?

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian I added [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39210488/2994949) to another question since this one was asking something slightly different, but I don't think there is a direct/easy way

Answer (score 5):

Well, not using colors (as not supported by markdown), but you can highlight cells/rows/columns of the table with [pandoc.table](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#highlighting-cells) and the [general pander method](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#generic-pander-method) by using **bold** or *italics* font face:

```
> library(pander)
> emphasize.rows(which(df$outcome == 2))
> pander(df)

-------------------------
 id   inputval   outcome 
---- ---------- ---------
 29     0.89        1    

*79*   *0.69*      *2*   

*41*   *0.64*      *2*   

*89*    *1*        *2*   

 95     0.66        1    

 5      0.71        1    

 53     0.54        1    

*90*   *0.6*       *2*   

*56*   *0.29*      *2*   

 46     0.14        4    

 96     0.97        1    

*46*   *0.91*      *2*   

 68     0.69        4    

 58     0.8         1    

 11     0.02        3    

 90     0.48        1    

 25     0.76        1    

 5      0.21        4    

 33     0.32        4    

*96*   *0.23*      *2*   
-------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

I've played around a good amount with formatting RMarkdown documents.

Since RMarkdown gets converted to LaTeX before the end PDF is generated, you can pass arguments that would work in LaTeX to RMarkdown. 
So, adding

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
```

in the heading of the RMarkdown document, and then adding something like

```
for(i in seq(1, nrow(yourDataframe), by = 2)){
  yourDataframe[i, ] <- paste0("\\color{purple}", yourDataframe[i, ])
  row.names(yourDataframe)[i] <- paste0("\\color{purple}", row.names(yourDataframe)[i])
}
```

will get you purple (or whatever color specified and allowed in the xcolor LaTeX package) entries in every other row of your table. Just another way to emphasize entries that isn't the base bold or italics given.

This isn't row highlighting, but could give you further customizable options.

*Tested with the pander package.

**You'll need to convert any factor columns to character columns for this method.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `ReporteRs`:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id = sample(1:100, 20, replace = TRUE),
  inputval = sample(seq(0, 1, by=0.01), 20, replace = TRUE),
  outcome  = sample(1:4, 20, replace = TRUE))

library( ReporteRs )
library( magrittr )

# create and format table
myft = df %>% FlexTable() %>% 
  setRowsColors( df$outcome == 1, 'magenta') %>% 
  setFlexTableWidths( c( 1, 1, 1) )

# create an html doc and send myft into
doc = bsdoc() %>% addFlexTable( myft )

# write the html file in a new dir
writeDoc( doc, "example_out/df.html")
```