# How to color specific cells in a Data Frame / Table in R?

Tags: css, r, formatting

I would like to color specific cells in the following dataframe. For example, in the inputval column, I would like to highlight cells in the range of `[0.8, 0.9)` magenta, and the cells in that same column in the range of `[0.7, 0.8)` blue. Similarly, I'd like the output column cells with a value of 1 to be colored magenta and those with value 4 to be colored blue. For the rest of the cells in the dataframe, I would like them to remain white.

I have the following reproducible code which highlights by row only, and limits me to coloring in magenta and white only. How can I add another color and do so by cell?

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id       = sample(1:100, 20, replace = TRUE),
                 inputval = sample(seq(0, 1, by=0.01), 20, replace = TRUE),
                 outcome  = sample(1:4, 20, replace = TRUE))

cols <- with(df, ifelse(outcome == 1, 'magenta', 'white'))

library('htmlTable')
htmlTable(as.matrix(df), col.rgroup = cols)
```

I realize that the issue for adding different colors is with the `ifelse` call in `with` that limits me to just magenta and white. How can I add another condition here?

While I know what's causing the multiple color issue, I'm pretty clueless about how to color only specific cells.

This is the same example as [the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114926/r-conditional-row-highlighting-in-html-table-created-using-xtable-or-kable).
 Thanks!

Comment: Check out the formatter package, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formattable/vignettes/formattable-data-frame.html . I got my table formatting needs totally covered with this (cell-by-cell formatting) using only this package, which calls the knitr::kable function.

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663159/conditional-coloring-of-cells-in-table

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you considered `DT`?

```
library(DT)
datatable(df, rownames = FALSE) %>%
  formatStyle(columns = "inputval", 
              background = styleInterval(c(0.7, 0.8, 0.9)-1e-6, c("white", "lightblue", "magenta", "white"))) %>%
  formatStyle(columns = "outcome", 
              background = styleEqual(c(1, 4), c("magenta", "lightblue")))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! That's as easy as it gets, thanks! 

If I happen to know the row numbers in each of the columns that I want to change color, how would I specify this? For example, in column `outcome`, say rows 1, 2, 4 I want to be blue & rows 3, 5, 6 to be magenta. Would the argument to `formatstyle` be something like `background = styleEqual(c(1,2, 4, 3, 5, 6), c(rep("lightblue", 3),rep("magenta", 3)) `? Of course I wouldn't explictly write out the row numbers. I'd have vector `blue` store the row numbers for blue, and the vector `magenta` store the row numbers for magenta.

Comment: I was able to more easily highlight based on the value in the cell instead of the row number just like you did for the column `outcome`. Once again, thank you! That table is beautiful!

Comment: How did you get the entire table into one image? When I export the table from Rstudio, part of it is missing.

Comment: You could set `options = list(paging = FALSE)` within `datatable`, open your `tempdir()`, then open the appropriate html in a browser and take a screenshot from within the browser using Nimbus or another screenshot tool.

Comment: +1 thanks. Selecting all -> copy -> paste on Libre Office works decently and maintains color and majority of table format for anyone's future reference. Nimbus or the like works best for smaller tables, maintaining  image quality.

Comment: what does the `-1e-6` bit do in `styleInterval(c(0.7, 0.8, 0.9)-1e-6` ?

Comment: @Laura It subtracts a small fraction. (I think to exclude the numbers - can't remember: 4 yrs ago)

Comment: @lukeA I am creating an HTML file with the code `print(xtable(extract1), type = "html", 
      sanitize.text.function = function(str) gsub("..", "Output", str, fixed = TRUE),
      file = "Output/extracted.html")` that uses `xtable` package. I want to color its specific column enteries, How should I approach to this.

Answer (score 6):

My answer below is really dumb.. Here is the proper way:

This feature is built into `htmlTable` via the `css.cell` argument:

> The `css.cell` element allows you to add any possible CSS style to your table cells. If you provide a vector the vector it is assummed that the styles should be repeated throughout the columns. If you provide a matrix of the same size as your x argument. If have `ncol(x) + 1` the first row will correspond to the rowname style. Correspondingly if the size is `nrow(x) + 1` it is assummed that the first row is the header row.

So Basically you just need to define a matrix of styles for each cell:

```
x <- head(cars)

## indices defining where the styles go
where <- rbind(c(2,2), c(2,1), c(5,2))
style <- c('background-color: red; color: white;',
           'border: solid 1px;',
           'font-weight: 900; color: blue;')

css.cell <- matrix('', nrow(x), ncol(x))
css.cell[where] <- style

#      [,1]                 [,2]                                  
# [1,] ""                   ""                                    
# [2,] "border: solid 1px;" "background-color: red; color: white;"
# [3,] ""                   ""                                    
# [4,] ""                   ""                                    
# [5,] ""                   "font-weight: 900; color: blue;"      
# [6,] ""                   ""                                

htmlTable(head(cars), css.cell = css.cell)
```

[image]

It's hard to tell unless you are swapping back and forth, but the spacing in this table and the similar one below is slightly different. The `inject_div` example looks a little more centered.

---

A little late, but @CyrusMohammadian made a comment on my other answer, and since the comment/question is the same as this one, I'll add the answer here rather than editing my answer which was for a (slightly) different question.

Tables can get complex, and everyone has different features they want. I don't think it is possible for [Max](http://github.com/gforge/htmlTable) to have solutions built-in for them all.

Therefore, the easiest way I think would be to (hackily) inject some html/css into your table (you could probably also do this after running `htmlTable`, ie directly in the html code, but this is easier I think):

```
#' Inject div
#' 
#' Inject an html division tag with style attribute.
#' 
#' @param x a matrix or data frame
#' @param where an \code{nx2} matrix of row and column indices or vector (of
#' the form c(row, col, row, col, ...)) specifying which cells to select
#' @param style vector of character string(s) applied to each cell, recycled
#' if necessary

inject_div <- function(x, where, style = 'background-color: lightgrey; border: solid 1px') {
  if (!all(sapply(style, nzchar)))
    return(x)
  where <- matrix(where, ncol = 2L, byrow = !is.matrix(where))
  style <- rep_len(style, nrow(where))
  if (length(where) > 0)
    x[where] <- sprintf('<div style=\'%s\'>%s</div>',
                      gsub(';*$', ';', style), x[where])
  x
}

library('htmlTable')
htmlTable(inject_div(head(cars), cbind(2,2)))
```

[image]

```
htmlTable(inject_div(head(cars), where = c(2,2,2,1,5,2),
                     ## equivalently
                     # where = rbind(c(2,2), c(2,1), c(5,2))
                     style = c('background-color: red; color: white;',
                               'border: solid 1px;',
                               'font-weight: 900; color: blue;')))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For adding additional colors, you would need more conditions, e.g. if you want to have a different color for an `outcome` of 1 and a specific `inputval`:

```
cols <- with(df, ifelse(outcome == 1,
                        ifelse(inputval == 5, 'magenta', 'red'),
                        'white')
```

So this should color anything with `outcome == 0` as white, and if `outcome == 1` and `inputval == 5`, it will be magenta; the others will be red.

For your other question, you can use a combination of `rgroup` and `cgroup` to specify which rows/columns you want to color, see the vignette, or see here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlTable/vignettes/tables.html

Comment: Thanks for this! What is a working example to specify the combination of rgroup and cgroup I need? The link you gave didn't have a clear example of selecting distinct cells, I believe.

Comment: Sorry, you may have to read the documentation and try some things out.