Can you highlight values in an array/table?
Lets say I have an array like the following:
d = matrix(rnorm(25,0,10), nrow = 5) %>% round(2)

which has given me:
    structure(c(-7.53, 23.22, -4.42, -5.38, 10.84, -36.38, -10.87, 
-7.44, -9.18, 0.71, 25.82, 16.18, -9.25, -7.04, 10.13, -11.55, 
-7.54, -4.74, -12.67, 20.46, -11.26, 6.57, -1.46, 4.54, -4.93
), dim = c(5L, 5L))

I'd like to somehow make it easier to spot cells whose absolute value is larger than 10, be it by highlighting them (could be in a xtable() print), or removing/changing to 0 other values. How can I do this?
My actual object is the .stdres output of chisq.test() (I can't share the data), if there's a way to highlight it directly in the function that also helps.

What exactly do you mean by highlight it directly in the function? Can you give an example of desired output? e.g. abs(d) > 10 shows you directly which cell is larger than 10.

Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872321/conditional-colouring-of-matrix-cells-in-r

If you're in R Studio and want some help with visual inspection, you can use reactable, kableExtra, flextable or similar.
Here's one with reactable:
reactable::reactable(
  aux, 
  defaultColDef = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
      
      color <- case_when(
        value >  10 ~ "lightblue",
        value < -10 ~ "lightpink",
        TRUE ~ "white")
      
      list(backgroundColor = color)}))

# Toy data
aux <- structure(
  c(-7.53, 23.22, -4.42, -5.38, 10.84, -36.38, -10.87, -7.44, -9.18, 
    0.71, 25.82, 16.18, -9.25, -7.04, 10.13, -11.55, -7.54, -4.74, 
    -12.67, 20.46, -11.26, 6.57, -1.46, 4.54, -4.93), 
  
  dim = c(5L, 5L))

The output is a html table in viewer pane:

